# ionic run android --device take too much time to run on android device

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using

```
ionic run android --device
```

or

```
ionic run android
```

my www folder is 25mb
and it takes too much time about 20 minutes to run on android device..
cordova cli is the latest : 6.4.0
anyone know why ?

Comment: did you try another device ?

Comment: honestly no, I will try

Comment: Use `ionic run android --verbose` to see whats going in the build/running details.

Comment: I tried another device same result , it takes too much time

Comment: what do you want to know about ionic run android --verbose ? @Darkoon

Comment: it may this did the long time for running or it doesn't matter : No scripts found for hook "before_deploy".or "after_run"

Comment: With --verbose you can see details of whats going on currently in building/running process. Look at it and try to find operation that is taking too much time.

Comment: he stop here : JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91

Comment: I'm sorry but stackoverflow didn't show me your replies here. Maybe delay is caused by searching for java in your PC? If you already fixed this problem, write down how you done this. Maybe it will help someone :)

Comment: i just remove the platform and i added it from new .